# How to combine sink.asFlux() with Server-Sent Events (SSE) using Spring WebFlux?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

I am using Spring Boot 2.7.8 with WebFlux.

I have a sink in my class like this:

```
    private final Sinks.Many<TaskEvent> sink = Sinks.many()
                                                    .multicast()
                                                    .onBackpressureBuffer();
```

This can be used to subscribe on like this:

```
 public Flux<List<TaskEvent>> subscribeToTaskUpdates() {
        return sink.asFlux()
                   .buffer(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                   .share();
    }
```

The `@Controller` uses this like this to push the updates as a Server-Sent Event (SSE) to the browser:

```
    @GetMapping("/transferdatestatuses/updates")
    public Flux<ServerSentEvent<TransferDateStatusesUpdateEvent>> subscribeToTransferDataStatusUpdates() {
        return monitoringSseBroker.subscribeToTaskUpdates()
                                  .map(taskEventList -> ServerSentEvent.<TransferDateStatusesUpdateEvent>builder()
                                                                       .data(TransferDateStatusesUpdateEvent.of(taskEventList))
                                                                       .build())
```

This works fine at first, but if I navigate away in my (Thymeleaf) web application to a page that has no connection with the SSE url and then go back, then the browser cannot connect anymore.

After some investigation, I found out that the problem is that the removal of the subscriber closes the flux and a new subscriber cannot connect anymore.

I have found 3 ways to fix it, but I don't understand the internals enough to decide which one is the best solution and if there any things I need to consider to decide what to use.

*Solution 1*

Disable the autoCancel on the sink by using the method overload of `onBackpressureBuffer` that allows to set this parameter:

```
    private final Sinks.Many<TaskEvent> sink = Sinks.many()
                                                    .multicast()
                                                    .onBackpressureBuffer(Queues.SMALL_BUFFER_SIZE, false);
```

*Solution 2*

Use `replay(0).autoConnect()` instead of `share()`:

```
public Flux<List<TaskEvent>> subscribeToTaskUpdates() {
        return sink.asFlux()
                   .buffer(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .replay(0).autoConnect();
                   
    }
```

*Solution 3*

Use `publish().autoConnect()` instead of `share()`:

```
public Flux<List<TaskEvent>> subscribeToTaskUpdates() {
        return sink.asFlux()
                   .buffer(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                   .publish().autoConnect();
    }
```

Which of the solutions are advisable to make sure a browser can disconnect and connect again later without problems?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if it is the root of your problem, but I didn't have that issue by using a keepAlive Flux.

```
val keepAlive = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(10)).map {
        ServerSentEvent.builder<Image>()
            .event(":keepalive")
            .build()
    }
    return Flux.merge(
        keepAlive,
        imageUpdateFlux
    )
```

Here is the whole file: [Github](https://github.com/tschuehly/PhotoQuest/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/de/tschuehly/photoquest/web/controller/ImageUpdateController.kt)